# Best way of filtering a list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a little confussed as to whether or not this is the best method to retrieve what I need.  I've got a list of files I've gotten from a directory using ftp.  I need to filter the list of file names depending on the file mask entered by the user into a `List<string>`.  I love LINQ, but not having used it for a few months I seem to have lost some of my skills already.  I've come up with the following so far.  I would be greatful if someone could verify what I've done is the best approach.

```
foreach (string s in fileMasks)
{
    fileNames.AddRange(
        directory.Files.ToList().Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith(s))
        .Select(b => b.Name)
    );
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `ToList()` call -- it's wasteful and adds nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just simplify your query

```
fileNames.AddRange(directory.Files.Select(f => f.Name).Where(a => a.EndsWith(s));
```

Comment: My original thought in using the .toList() was so I could get to the .ForEach() but I kind of got lost on how to select each item in the .ForEach() so gave up and went for the above. Thanks I've removed it.

Comment: @zeencat don't use `.ForEach()` use a `foreach` block

Comment: @zeencat List.ForEach is a void method that allows you to repeatedly call a void method using each item of the list as a parameter.  As you've discovered, that's slightly different from the linq approach, where you operate on a sequence to return a different sequence.

Comment: @Jodrell Can I enquire as to why you recommend that?

Comment: @zeencat indeed you may. First, I agree with Eric Lippert's comments http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx and second, Microsoft regret it http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/758f7b98-e3ce-41e5-82a2-109f1df446c2

Answer (score 2):

It seems OK, but you can skip the `.ToList()` in the middle.

You could also rewrite with query syntax

```
fileNames.AddRange(
    from file in directory.Files
    where file.Name.EndsWith
    select file.Name
);
```

I often find the query syntax more easy to read.

Comment: Removing the `ToList()` is a good idea. The readability of the query syntax is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `foreach` loops and `AddRange`, you could use the `SelectMany` extension method:

```
List<string> result = directory
    .Files
    .SelectMany(f => fileMasks.Where(m => f.Name.EndsWith(m)), (f, m) => f.Name)
    .ToList();
```

or if you prefer the using the LINQ syntax:

```
List<string> result =
    (from f in directory.GetFiles()
    from m in fileMasks
    where f.Name.EndsWith(m)
    select f.Name).ToList();
```

That's LINQ. But since you are dealing with filtering directories you could use file masks. The `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` method allow you to do this.

Comment: I can't use the DirectoryInfo.GetFiles because I'm trying to filter the filenames on an ftp site not my local path.  The directory is an instance of winscp's RemoteDirectoryInfo class.

Comment: I see. I did a small update to my answer in the SelectMany call as I initially forgot to select the file name as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without foreach statement

```
fileNames.AddRange(
    (from file in directory.Files
    from m in fileMasks
    where file.Name.EndsWith(m)
    select file.Name));
```